# arcpy Multiple ring buffer: not working for OUTSIDE_ONLY?

Tags: arcpy, buffer, error-000800

I am trying to create multiple buffers surrounding input polygon fc. My code works well if I run default variables. However, if I would like to keep only outside buffers, I got back and error:

```
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of ALL | NONE.
Failed to execute (MultipleRingBuffer).
```

Do you have any idea, why my script runs in an error for "outside polygons"? It runs well when run as a tool from ArcToolbox. I am using ArcGIS 10.4, python 2.7.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True 

# Define variables
inFC = "C:/Users/inFC"
outLoc = "C:/Users/unique.gdb"
distances = [100, 500, 1000]
bufferUnit = "meters"

outBuff = outLoc + "/" + "b_" + "Koprova" 

# Create buffers
arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(inFC, outBuff,
                                  distances, bufferUnit,
                                  "", "OUTSIDE_ONLY")  # this works only with "ALL" instead of "OUTSIDE_ONLY"
```

Comment: An empty string is **not** a valid placeholder. Use `#` or one of `ALL`/`NONE`, or specify `outside_polygons_only=OUTSIDE_ONLY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 6th parameter of the tool is `Dissolve_option` and takes either ALL or NONE as the error message states. The parameter allowing you to specify that you want outside buffers only is the 7th. So either add an empty parameter before "OUTSIDE_ONLY", or omit the empty parameters and specify the parameter's name as @Vince suggests:

```
arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(inFC, outBuff, distances, 
bufferUnit, "", "", "OUTSIDE_ONLY") 

arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(inFC, outBuff, distances, 
bufferUnit, Outside_Polygons_Only="OUTSIDE_ONLY")
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed the specification of this parameter...